# HTML select based off of user info for state

Tags: php, html, variables, select, state

```
<select name="state" class="input-small" selected="<? if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ echo $row_login['state']; }?>">
  <option value="AL">AL</option>
  <option value="AK">AK</option>
  <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
  <option value="AR">AR</option>
  <option value="CA">CA</option>
```

I am creating a user profile edit section and need the users pre-selected state to show up as the list default. How can I manage to do this?

Preferably something that doesnt involve jquery because it seems like there should be a simple solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: we need more context.. are you asking if you should use session data? or how to use session data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="state" class="input-small">
<?php

$states = array('AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL', 
'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 
'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 
'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 
'WI', 'WY');

foreach ($states as $state)
{
    echo '<option ';
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $row_login['state'] == $state)
    {
        echo 'selected="selected" ';
    }
    echo 'value="' . $state . '">' . $state . "</option>\n";
}

?>
</select>
```

Just replace your options list with the above, it will dynamically create the list then and when printing out each option will check to see if that state option is the one the user has. If it is then it will select that as the default. A lot easier than having to do an if() statement 50 times.

Comment: I tried using this although even though the name for the select option is still state it is not posting back to mysql. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: You would need to post the code for the page this form submits to.

Comment: To be precise it still sends a change to mysql however it removes whatever the state used to be and fills it in with a blank. Perhaps the variable for the value is wrong?

Comment: in form processing code please run print_r($_POST); and see what the value for 'state' is and if it is even being passed. The above code will send the state abbreviation value for the currently selected state which would be the user's state.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that because a modal is being used to pass the variables to a register page and doesn't actually go to the page once it has been submitted. However I doubt it would echo back since there is an empty variable being passed to mysql

Comment: Well you need to check to see if the value is being properly submitted to the form and that is the best way server-side. The empty value being passed to mysql can be a completely different issue then. Somewhere along the line the value is lost. If you check the HTML source of the form page and it is all correctly done, then it has nothing to do with the HTML, but rather some PHP code which is handling the form processing. If that is the case please open a question for that since it would require you to post the code that does the processing.

Comment: Alright so turns out I'm a moron and had the wrong value scheme.... it was res_state instead of state. Sorry to make you chase this thing but I appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

a hassle way to do it is, on each option, you echo selected if the user's state is equal to the option's state. Assuming the user's state is in `$row_login['state'];`, it will be something like:

```
<option value="AL" <?php if($row_login['state'] == "AL") echo " selected "; ?> >AL</option>
```

and do that for each option. usually you'd want to do this in a much automated fashion.

Comment: Well this works, although it seems like there should be a simpler solution then to change all of the states.

Comment: not without a function that will return all the states, in which case you would need to still write all that out anyways ;) or use jquery, but you said you want to avoid that.

Comment: is the jquery solution simpler? I only avoid it because I have yet to become friends with it.

Comment: if you use jquery, it'll be simple as something like $('.input-small').each(function() { if($(this).val() == "<?php echo $row_login['state']; ?>") $(this).prop('selected','selected'); });

Comment: This would be overkill to do for 50 states, looping through a list of states is the best option without having to use jQuery.

Comment: that is why i said it is a hassle way to do. but is easy to implement